# Is it possible to show some text in Cmd after a git commit command is done?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, cmder

I want to show a message on Cmder every time I do "git commit".

I want it to be a positive reinforcement like "Yeah! Well done! Keep going" :)

Is it possible to do it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you ask without being jury-rigged, what you need is a ***git hook***.

***They are described in detail  [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)***

There are four events during the `git commit` process that you can hook and pump our your message (or do other things).

- pre-commit
- prepare-commit-msg
- commit-msg
- post-commit

The descriptions for these events to hook on can also be found in the above link.
It isn't hard.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Señor CMasMas

Answer (score 1):

Write an alias for your operating system. For example, a `.bat` file in Windows. Which would write something on the screen with `echo` and run the command.

Example:
`commit.bat`

```
git commit
echo "Good job, keep up the great work!"
```

You could use Fortune in fact.
Fortune is a great little app which has like motivational messages, riddles and whatnot.
So I would just call the commit command and then fortune.

See:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fortune - a wiki page from Arch Wiki
https://www.bgreco.net/fortune - A Windows example with PowerShell
https://github.com/shlomif/fortune-mod - The original repository/source code (you don't need this.)

Ps.: I would look into a site/service that can track your progress via tickets and milestones instead. Because commit is not really a sign of progress. So a site that could integrate with Github, Bitbucket, or whatever you use. And just use the issue tracker and milestone system. And if you make a good progress, it'd congratulate/motivate. If not, well, demotivate? I don't know. :D

Comment: Thank you very very much @Apache.